# How to multithread in C

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing

Is there a way I can multi thread in windows using c. I wanted to execute a function separately from the main so that it can always check independently from the main, while still able to continue performing what is in main. Something like this:

```
int main(void){
    int login = 0,status = 1;

    checkChanges(); // This function is what needs to run independently from the execution of the main

    while(status){
        if(!login || status == 2)
            login = loginFuntion();
        else
            status = menuFunction();
    }

    terminate();
}
```

Comment: Internet search of "c threading windows"?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-threads

Comment: yeahh I guess this is it, thanks